# На сайте вылез код наружу

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Приветствую. При переносе сайта на странице вылез наружу код. все нужные блоки выводятся. Прошу помощи, ребята. Не пойму в чем дело, может база криво переехала, хотя норм все вроде. Вот страница: http://footbik.com/o-klube/otzyvy/

Comment: Проверьте внимательно код на наличие <?php

Comment: Все есть. Аналогичный код страницы работает на оригинальном сайте без проблем.

Comment: Можно вы попытаетесь вывести переменную например через print_r с таким содержанием. Покажите скриншот где выводится данный код.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hdba11

Comment: Оберните все <?  в <?php массовой заменой символов

Comment: Не помогло. http://prntscr.com/hdbe8y

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю, вот виновник торжества.
[image: Картинка]

Comment: Спасибо за желание помочь. Но подскажите пожалуйста что с этим сделать можно?

Comment: Все. Я понял. Удалил и все ок. Спасибо за помощь!)

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, пожалуйста отметье его.

Comment: @МаксимБогданов если ответ помог -  отметьте его решённым.